# Hanging MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a *MapReduce* job(***`1200 mappers, 1 reducer`***) which is hanging at `Map -100%` and `Reduce - 0%`.

The reducer is stuck at the fetch stage forever.

Now I want to kill the job and then resume the same job.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say what's happening without more information on the job, but what might be happening is that the transfer of data from 1200 mappers -> 1 reducer is taking a really long time.

To answer your question, you can't kill the job and resume the job again in the same state. You'll have to kill it and restart the job.

Here's the command to kill the job:

```
hadoop job -kill <job_id>
```

Comment: Thanks Chaos for the quick reply. Actually I am running a hive query which has a order by clause with three columns. Order By uses a single reducer. I have seen the query plan using explain, it has two root stages 1. Map 2. Reduce. In map stage it executes the where clause and  in reduce it does a fetch. After having a look at the TT log files, I did not find any errors as such. I checked the JT web UI and the reduce task is never attempted. I have no clue on how to go ahead.

Comment: can you try executing your query with `limit 1`? That way it will only output 1 record & we'll know more about whether it's an issue with the query or the data size.

Comment: Chaos, I tired with limit 1 and the same results. When I remove order by clause that works fine. So essentially it has got to do something with the reducer fetch phase. I made the following change set io.sort.mb=150;set io.sort.record.percent=0.138;set io.sort.spill.percent=1.0; and ran the query. Now in TT logs I see the following err,

Comment: 2014-07-21 13:53:01,348 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2014-07-21 13:53:01,350 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapRedWork(Utilities.java:226)